# WPF GridSplitter after resize

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridsplitter

Once the gridsplitter is used to resize a grid the row * will not reclaim the space when the other rows are collapsed.

I have the following grid in a master detail view with three rows.  A data grid on top a splitter in the middle and a contentcontrol view in the last row.  The splitter has a close button on it to collapse the detail.  This all works with the exception that once the user resizes using the gridsplitter.

```
    <Grid Margin="3,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource CollapsableRow}"/><!-- Splitter Here -->
        <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource CollapsableRow}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The GridSplitter style:

```
    <Style x:Key="gridSplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsItemSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToShow},ConverterParameter='Visible|Collapsed'}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="#FF6593CF" />
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="7,7,7,7" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNS" /></Style>
```

Like I said the collapse works correctly unless the gridsplitter is used to resize.  After that the whitespace stays.

EDIT: 
H.B. and codenaked had simple and consistant suggestions so and I attempted to implement them w/o success in a data trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="CollapsableRow" TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" Value="0"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" Value="Auto"/>
        </DataTrigger>            
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the grid splitter and detail were already being hidden Visibility was the obvious choice to reset the next row definition height.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Grid splitter that show or hides the following row when the visibility of the splitter is changed. 
/// </summary>
public class HidableGridSplitter : GridSplitter { 

    GridLength height;

    public HidableGridSplitter()
    {
        this.IsVisibleChanged += HideableGridSplitter_IsVisibleChanged;
        this.Initialized += HideableGridSplitter_Initialized;
    }

    void HideableGridSplitter_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cache the initial RowDefinition height,
        //so it is not always assumed to be "Auto"
        Grid parent = base.Parent as Grid;
        if (parent == null) return;
        int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(this);
        if (rowIndex + 1 >= parent.RowDefinitions.Count) return;
        var lastRow = parent.RowDefinitions[rowIndex + 1];
        height = lastRow.Height;
    }

    void HideableGridSplitter_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid parent = base.Parent as Grid;
        if (parent == null) return;

        int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(this);

        if (rowIndex + 1 >= parent.RowDefinitions.Count) return;

        var lastRow = parent.RowDefinitions[rowIndex + 1];

        if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            lastRow.Height = height;
        }
        else
        {
            height = lastRow.Height; 
            lastRow.Height = new GridLength(0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use animation to solve the row/column definition override by gridsplitter. See my answer to a similar question at [GridSplitter overrides ColumnDefinition's style trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413507/221819)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GridSplitter the Heights are no longer `Auto` but concrete values. You need to manually change the values back either using a style or events and code behind, e.g. this resets a auto-size column on double-click:

```cs
private void ColumnSplitter_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ColumnTreeView.Width.IsAuto) ColumnTreeView.Width = new GridLength();
}
```

Comment: Setting the gridlength in code is what needs to done.  However double click isn't going to work in this case.  The grid splitter is being styled and its actually a button on the splitter that does the closing.  I choose to override the grid splitter and set the parent.hiegth there.

Comment: My code was just an example, i never expected you do no anything upon `DoubleClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, the GridSplitter will resize the previous and next rows. You can see this in action with this code:

```
<Grid Margin="3,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row0" Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row2" Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Red" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=row0, Path=Height}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource gridSplitterStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="50">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=row2, Path=Height}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The last row's size will actually change from Auto to a fixed height. So even if you collapse the content in that row, it will still take up the specified space. You'd need to reset the row to `Height="Auto"` to truly collapse it with it's content.

Comment: I like your and H.B. s suggetion and implmented a style trigger on the row to do so:

Comment: didn't work :( sincee the rowDefinition needs a new instance of GridLength to be set.

Comment: @Ryan - Not sure I understand. If you set `this.row2.Height = GridLength.Auto;` then it would reset it.