# Why the trigger doesn't work after GridSplitter is dragged

Tags: wpf, xaml

Due to project privacy protection, I can't paste the product code here. So I made a simple example to show the problem.

I have a window like this:
[image]

When I click the Right button, I want the Right Column hide and the Left Column Stretch to full window:

[image]

Here is my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="rightCol" MinWidth="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Height="100" Content="Left" />
        </StackPanel>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="right" Grid.Column="2" >
            <Button Height="100" Content="Right" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is my code-behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            var b = new Binding("Visibility")
            {
                Source = this.right
            };

            var style = new Style(typeof(ColumnDefinition))
            {
                Setters = 
                {
                    new Setter(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(300)),
                    new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty, 0.0),
                }
            };

            style.Triggers.Add(new DataTrigger()
            {
                Binding = b,
                Value = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed,
                Setters = 
                    { 
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(0)),
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MaxWidthProperty, double.PositiveInfinity),
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty, 0.0),
                    }
            });

            this.rightCol.Style = style;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.right.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

When I run it and Click the Right button, it works fine. But **if I drag the GridSplitter before I Click the Right button**, the trigger doesn't work:
[image]

Why this happened?

Note:
If I use below code, it can work.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.right.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.rightCol.Width = new GridLength(0);
}
```

But is there any way to use trigger?

Comment: The trigger seems to have worked, the right column is collapsed as you can see from the button not being visible. However, once you drag the splitter, I assume that the left column gets a fixed size and therefore doesn't fill up the entire grid.

Comment: Is it possible to change back the left column to Stretch?

Comment: I believe you can change it to Stretch before you set the right column's visibility to Collapsed.

Comment: Could you show it in code?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from this link:
[GridSplitter overrides ColumnDefinition's style trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548461/gridsplitter-overrides-columndefinitions-style-trigger/13413507#13413507)

So below code works fine:

```
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var b = new Binding("Visibility")
            {
                Source = this.rightPane,
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
            };

            var style = new Style(typeof(ColumnDefinition))
            {
                Setters = 
                {
                    new Setter(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(300)),
                    new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty, 0.0),
                }
            };

            /*
            style.Triggers.Add(new DataTrigger()
            {
                Binding = b,
                Value = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed,
                Setters = 
                    { 
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(0)),
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MaxWidthProperty, double.PositiveInfinity),
                        new Setter(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty, 0.0),
                    }
            });*/
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames oaf = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            DiscreteObjectKeyFrame disobj = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();
            disobj.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
            disobj.Value = GridLength.Auto;
            oaf.KeyFrames.Add(disobj);
            sb.Children.Add(oaf);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(oaf, new PropertyPath(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty));

            var actionBegin = new BeginStoryboard();
            actionBegin.Storyboard = sb;
            actionBegin.Name="BeginStoryboard1";

            var actionEnd = new RemoveStoryboard();
            actionEnd.BeginStoryboardName = "BeginStoryboard1";

            var trigger = new DataTrigger()
            {
                Binding = b,
                Value = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
            };

            trigger.EnterActions.Add(actionBegin);
            trigger.ExitActions.Add(actionEnd);
            style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            style.RegisterName(actionBegin.Name, actionBegin);
            this.rightCol.Style = style;
        }
```